# javascript code is not running when location is moved

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function which is called by a 'onsubmit' within a form (Coldfusion).

```
<form action    = "person2aa.cfm" 
    name        = "pers2form"
    method      = "post"
    style       = "margin-left: 125px"
    onsubmit    = "return test()">
```

When the function test() is located directly below this form statement it works correctly:

```
<script>
function test(){ 
alert("got to test");
var yesa = document.getElementById('yesnoa').value;
var yesb = document.getElementById('yesnob').value;

var xx = document.getElementById('ln').value;
var x = xx.trim();
alert('supbpers2 x is ' + x); 
if (x < "!"){
 document.getElementById('writeval').innerHTML = "You must enter a last name.";
 return false;}
 else
 return true;
}
</script>
```

(The remainder of the form continues below this script).

When I place this function anywhere else, it does not run.  I have tried it in the header of the html page, and also on another page, person.js, to which the link is:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "person.js"> </script>
```

The first alert 'got to test' runs in these places, but the first line starting var yesa = does not execute and the function therefore does not execute either.

The id's 'yesnoa', 'yesnob', 'ln' and 'writeval' are in the code and are correct (or the inline script would not run, but I checked anyway).

I previously had this script (minus the alerts) in the header section of my program, and it was working at one point.  I have returned to retest the program some months later and the script was not functioning. I have not made any changes to this script at any time. The program itself was altered by the addition of 4 trivial queries to do various things but all look something like this:

```
<cfquery name = 'aa11' datasource = "Moxart">
update NameInfoDb
set perloc = <cfqueryparam value = "#perloc#">
</cfquery>
```

I cannot think of any connection between these additional queries and the failure of the javascript.

Can anyone explain what the problem might be?  There must be an explanation, and I need to know it so I will not repeat whatever the bad code is.

Comment: are there any errors in the browsers developer tools console?

Comment: firebug shows nothing at all -- I'll see if the tools menu comes up with somehing.

Comment: firebug is a piece of rubbish at times ... built in dev tools are far more reliable

Comment: I looked at the debugger in Firefox.  It is showing person.js but it is not showing any errors.  However, I've never used this tool.  Do I have to click something to see errors?

Comment: just go to the console tab in dev tools (shortcut is ctrl+shift+k)

Comment: all I got was Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. person1aa.cfm
The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.  I did not write any of that code, nor the script that disables things; nor do I know how to re-enable it.